# show image name through browse field in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I show image name through the browse field. Sorry that, I am new in PHP.
I use this code, but it's not working

```
<input
  id="photo"
  type="file"
  value="<?php echo $results['image'];?>"
  class="form-control"
  name="image" />
```

Comment: what do you meen with 'browse field'? If you meen the address bar of your browser and you write something like `test.php?image=myfilename.jpg` you'll get that value as `$_GET['image']` in php.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set `$results['image']` as the selected value of the input field? If so, that's not possible. You cannot programmatically select a file in a file input due to security restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

You can not show a image on a input field.

What you can do is:

```
<img src="allYourDomainURL/<?php echo $results['image'];?>" />
```

That would effectively show a real image to the user.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing what you want to do is to show inside the input type file the image you uploaded once the form is submitted. I am afraid that is not possible.

What you can do is save the image on a folder inside your project, save that into a variable, for example $image. Then show it inside your form, you can even create a link so that when they click on it the image will appear on a different tab.

```
<a href="ProjectUrl/image/<?php echo $image; ?>" target='_blank' ><img src="Project/image/ <?php echo $image; ?> "></a>
```